# Add the date of creation to a filename in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I need to create a report(.txt) and I want to reference each sessions of tests, so I wanted that for each simulations, I add the date to name of my report. 
Like Report_01-19-2017-12:53.txt
So far I have been able to create either a file with the date inside with :

```
$system("date > sDate");
```

or display it on my simulation software with :

```
$system("date");
```

So far,My code look like :

```
 string     filename;
 reg [8*30:1]   data; // the date is of 29 characters in size
 string     sDate;
 integer    scan_file,data_file    ;
 initial begin
      $system("date > data");
      data_file = $fopen("data", "r");
      scan_file = $fscanf(sDate,"%s", data); 
      $fclose("data"); 
      [...]
      filename = {filename,sDate};
     Report_Task = $fopen(filename,"a");   [...]
   end
```

sDate contains nothing, date contains the date...
I tried `string` and `reg` for `filename` and `sDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean

```
scan_file = $fscanf(data_file, "%s", sDate);
```

where, if the read is successful, `scan_file` will be equal to 1 (the number of items read). (So, you probably didn't want to call it `scan_file`.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going through files to get the date, you could use `svlib`. Chapter 9 of the [documentation](https://eda-playground.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/svlib-userguide-0.3.pdf) illustrates how to get information about the current time.